# How to redirect to main page with in frame from servlet?

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I have 3 frames in screen , using frameset I did like this.

index.thml

```
<frameset rows="75%,25%">
    <frameset cols="20%,80%">
        <frame src="TreeGroup.jsp" name="left" id="f1"/>
        <frame src="DisplayMap.jsp"   name="top" id="f2"/>
    </frameset>
    <frame src="Tabs.jsp" name="bottom"/>
 </frameset>
```

in frame `f1` there is a link, if I click that , it opens `VehicleReg` in frame `f2`. In frame `f2` I click submit, control goes to Servlet and servlet redirect to index.html. Here is I am facing problem ,

In Servlet I do as `response.sendRedirect("index.html")`

but in Browser, It is already in `index.html` , after servlet response in frame `f2` it opens `index.html`. I mean it redirects `index.html` with in frame `f2`. How to avoid this. I want after servlet response a fresh `index.html`. Can anyone help me in this please.

Comment: frames are deprecated, why are you using them in the first place? Use `target` on form to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Add the following JavaScript code between the `<head>` tags of your `index.html` page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    if (top.location != self.location) {
      top.location.href = self.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

This makes your index page automatically break out of the frames and reload itself.